# Prove that $|p(x)| \ge |a_o|\cdot|x^n|\cdot [1-\frac{1}{R}(|\frac{a_1}{a_o}|+|\frac{a_2}{a_o}|+...+|\frac{a_n}{a_o}|)] $

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $n$ be a natural number, and let $p(x)=a_ox^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_n$ be a polynomial with real coefficients and $a_o \ne 0$. Assume $|x|\gt R$, where $R$ is a fixed positive real number.

Prove that $|p(x)| \ge |a_o|\cdot|x^n|\cdot [1-\frac{1}{R}(|\frac{a_1}{a_o}|+|\frac{a_2}{a_o}|+...+|\frac{a_n}{a_o}|)] $

Moreover, prove that if $R$ is large enough then the quantity in brackets is positive.

The proof requires the use of the triangle inequality, and I am unsure of it is supposed to be applied. It may also require induction which I assume could be used afterwards. I have tried to think of ways to make the left hand side look more like something I could apply the triangle inequality to, but having the $R$ in there confuses me.